# Define with only 1 argument

Tags: c

I'm reading external C code, and I found the following line of code:

```
#define __MAIN_C__
```

where `#define` is given only one "argument" (namely `__MAIN_C__`).

Is this just a placeholder, or can it have a function?

Comment: You might want to read up a little more on the [C pre-processor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor).

Comment: It should be noted that `__MAIN_C__` is not a legal identifier for an application to use. It's reserved for the implementation.

Comment: @R..: Could you provide more details?

Comment: Identifiers beginning with two underscores or an underscore followed by a capital letter may not be used by application code. They're reserved for internal use by the C implementation (e.g. in the standard library headers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That `#define` will define `__MAIN_C__` **to no value** (thanks to n.m. and a simple test program). It's a shortcut when you need something `#define`d when you don't care what it's defined to. In that case, somewhere in your code, you'd probably just see:

```
#ifdef __MAIN_C__
```

And that doesn't care what specific value it has, as long as it's defined (and perhaps nonzero).

You'll very often see this for [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), like so:

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_H
#define MYHEADER_H

// stuff here

#endif
```

This is similar to doing this in the compile flags:

```
gcc -D__MAIN_C__ main.c
```

If you want to see that it's defined to nothing, try to compile this and watch it fail:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TEST

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%d\n", TEST);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @n.m. Thanks, just verified -- it's literally defined as nothing, but defined nonetheless.

Comment: If used in code, it will be replaced with empty space.  The preprocessor, however, will interpret the value as being "true" for any #ifdef or similar statements.

Comment: When you do this, does it use up space in memory? And if so, how much?

Comment: No. All preprocessor directives such as these are handled before compilation. If something gets compiled to nothing, it typically gets optimized out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can accomplish something. If you look, there's a pretty decent chance you'll find something like: `#ifdef __MAIN_C__` somewhere -- this just checks whether the symbol has been defined, regardless of the value (if any) given.

Answer (score 1):

A define in this case simply sets **MAIN_C**.  No value is assigned, but the preprocessor will interperet **MAIN_C** as "true".  Generally, defines like these are used to include or exclude code before compilation, using something like the following:

```
#define WIN32

#ifdef WIN32
//some win32-specific code
#else
//some other code

#endif
```

Comment: I know.  I realized right after I posted and corrected it.  Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

This definition makes `__MAIN_C__` to expand (roughly speaking) to nothing.

A possible use:

```
#ifdef __MAIN_C__
foo(bar);
#endif
```

Another one:

```
#ifdef PLAIN_OLD_OS
#define __MAIN_C__
#else
#define __MAIN_C__ __os_specific_attribute(dllsomething)
#endif

__MAIN_C__ int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
```